# How do I block all IP addresses from connecting remotely to Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, blocking, docker, remote, limits

I want access to remote cassandra with one ip address. how can I change cassandra.yaml to block all ip address except ip that I want to connect?

Can I do by cassandra.yaml ?

Comment: Could you define "connect" here? Connect = SSH/connect via Drivers/etc.,?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this exactly what a *Firewall* does for you?

Isn't it better to let this *purpose-built* software take the brunt of any "attack", rather than letting the attacker *most* of the way into your server and asking Cassandra to try to defend "herself" ...   ?

As a certain, fictional engineer is famed for saying:

> The Right Tool for the Right Job ...

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot block or allow IP addresses with Cassandra, I recommend enabling authentication, authorization, and [client-to-node SSL/TLS encryption](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/trunk/cassandra/operating/security.html). This way, anyone from another IP address (who tries to access your cluster), will not have the required valid credentials or TLS certificate; and will not be allowed to connect to your cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You don't configure network access rules in the database itself. You need to do this at the network layer using hardware or software firewalls.

With firewalls, you can configure access control lists (ACLs) such that only certain devices/network segments (typically your app servers) have connectivity to the database. Cheers!